# Redirection error in controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

i cant seem to fix my issue when i delete a task it redirects me to dashboard i can see in controller it is currently redirecting to /dashboard page however when i try to fix this it just errors out :/ i want it to acheive the same result the create redirection does

```
public function createTaskPage(Request $request, $slug) {

    $project = Project::where('slug', $slug)->firstOrFail();

    // Validate it has a body.
    $validate = validator(
            $request->toArray(), [
        'task' => 'required',
    ]);

    if ($validate->fails()) {
        return response()->json([], 400);
    }
    $tasks = new Task;
    $tasks->project_id = $project->id;
    $tasks->body = $request->task;
    $tasksCreate = Auth::user()->tasks()->save($tasks);
    //return response()->json([], 201);
    return redirect()->to('/project/' . $project->slug);
}

public function doDeleteTask($id) {
    try {
        $tasks = Task::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->findOrFail($id);
    } catch (\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException $ex) {
        return response()->json([], 404);
    }
    $tasks->delete();
    //return response()->json([], 204);
    return redirect()->to('/dashboard');
}
```

This is the Form where delete button is

```
<div class="col-md-3">
<div class="panel panel-default shadow">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row text-center">
            <h4><strong>{{ str_limit(strip_tags($project->name), 20) }}</strong></h4>
            <h5>{{ $project->created_at }}</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="row text-center" style="margin:5px;">
            {{ ($project->description) }}
        </div>
        <div class="row text-center">
            <form action="{{ url('/project/'.$project->id) }}" method="POST">
                {{ csrf_field() }}
                {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-link btn-sm" onclick="return ConfirmDelete(this)" style="margin:5px;"><i class="fa fa-ban fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                <a href="{{ url('/project/' . $project->slug) }}" class="btn btn-link btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            </form>              
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my Delete route & create route

```
Route::delete('/task/{id}', 'TaskController@doDeleteTask'); // Delete a task
Route::post('/project/{slug}/task', 'TaskController@createTaskPage')->name('task');
```

Comment: What is your route file looks like

Comment: Route::delete('/task/{id}', 'TaskController@doDeleteTask'); // Delete a task

Comment: I meant the route file. If the functionality seems to be OK yet has a redirecting issue, there can be a issue with the route file (with other routes)

Comment: How do you "fix it" ? I mean it's not broken, it's behaving in the way that it's been coded to behave. The issue is when you modify the code therefore it would be better to show us what the code which produces the error looks like.

Comment: @apokryfos  i have editted my answer to show more code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a project relation defined in tasks, you can do this:

```
public function doDeleteTask($id) {
    try {
        $tasks = Task::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->findOrFail($id);
    } catch (\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException $ex) {
        return response()->json([], 404);
    }
   $project = $tasks->project;
   $tasks->delete();

   return redirect()->to('/project/' . $project->slug);
}
```